# AuthorizationStatus for Contacts not changing when switched on

Tags: ios, contacts, cncontact

Im writing an app which is available from iOS 7. And I'm using contacts for retrieving data of the user which is logged in his connection (in the app).

I've written some code which checks if the

```
CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];
```

Is not 3 -> Authorised. When this is the case I'm showing a view which asks to go to the settings and set the contacts accessibility on true.

But when I return back to the app, and I've changed the status. It still remains the previous value. Anyone with a solution?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Found the same issue on the iOS Simulator for iOS 9 and above. After further experimentation, on the physical device, I was able to confirm that the aforementioned behavior is not showing up. Hence, this leads me to believe that it might be limited to the simulator.